# is it possible to have a mixed variable in Java like in PHP?

Tags: java, php, json

For example in PHP:

```
<?php

    $my_var = 1;
    $my_var = [ "1" ]; // no problem
```

In Java, I tried to make a Class with a mixed argument:

```
class MyClass {
  public String my_var; 
}

MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.my_var = "ok";
c.my_var = 1; // error during compilation time
```

The reason I am asking that is because I am using jersey with json and I try to make a Feedback Class.

One argument in my Feedback class is the data to send back to the front-end in an Ajax manner. Sometimes `data` is a normal string:

```
`{ "data" : "hello world" }`
```

Sometimes it can be an array

```
`{ "data" : [ "hello", "world" ] }` or `{ "data" : [ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 2 }, ... ] }`
```

I am a real noobies when it comes to the Java language and libraries. The only solution I can think of now is to override the `toString` method for the objects involved in the Json encoding but "toString"'ing a `List` will give me something like that,

```
 `{ "data" : "[ ...]" }` which is incorrect.
```

Comment: Making it of `Object` type is the only way, but be aware this is _really_ un-Java-ish.  Better practice is to have an interface for the methods you need, and implement classes for all the possibilities.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'll be careful, thanks this works now.

Comment: For the record: I added some more content to my answer; covering the *real* question in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
Object c = new Object();
c = new String("hi"); //valid
c = new Integer(1); //valid
```

And then to check what type of variable it is you can use `instanceof`

You can also make it an array or a list, and if you want to use `toString` on it generically to print out any object, you can make your own list class with an overridden `toString` method that prints it nicely, and use that class in your object

using objects with nice `toString` methods means that you won't have to use `instanceof` if all you want to do is get a string representation of the object

Comment: There is no need to use new explicitly there: `c = "hi"; c = 1;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner true but i wanted to illustrate what is actually happening on the back end

Answer (score 1):

Java is a **statically** typed language; and "dynamics" are limited to things such as assigning sub class values to a super class variable, like:

```
Object o = "a string";
o = new Double(42.0);
```

So it looks like `o` can be both, String and Integer. But as said; that is because Object is a super type of **both** those classes.

This for example:

```
String s = "meow";
s = 42;
```

leads to a **compiler** error. What would work again would be `s = Integer.toString(42)` for example.

Similarly, you could do:

```
Object o = new int[5];
```

because in Java *any* reference type (including arrays) is a sub class of Object.

And just to be precise: the Java people think this is an *advantage*. Because it allows more checking at compile time - catching many errors that require you to write/run unit tests in those dynamic languages where a duck can meow like a cat and still be barking dog in the end.

Coming back to your question: from a *Java* point of view, an array is not the same as a string. And therefore you would not a low such a JSON representation. In other words: I would *first* try to change the JSON format.

If that is **not** possible, I would look into *customized* JSON de/serialization code - in order to have the framework decide which case is given and do the appropriate thing. Just as inspiration, you can have a look how this can be done with [gson](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-custom-serializer-deserializer/).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't do that in Java yet, so you'd have to make an indirect workaround, but there are plans to implement typeless objects/variables in Java version 10 (currently at 8, almost moved to 9)

Answer (score 0):

Think oops way,

Have an Interface like `FeedBackResponse` , Have different implementation classes for each of the cases, make them implement `FeedBackResponse`. 
Each class will have different attributes.

Serialize the object using json library.

Ex,

```
FeedBackResponse response = getResponse("Some Service");
return jsonLib.serialize(response);
```

Factory

```
private FeedBackResponse getResponse(String attr){
// based on attr create ur object here.
}
```